Why doesn’t the ARP command show the router's wireless MAC address?
The ARP command doesn't want to show the MAC addresses I see for my router via its interface.
It only shows the MAC addresses for the routers ethernet/LAN.
Is there a way to get windows to display the wireless MAC?
It won't show up even while I'm on Wi-Fi.

That's normal; the Wi-Fi access point's BSSID that's used to establish the wireless link is functionally separate from the MAC address that's used with IP/ARP – it's not associated with any IP address so it has no place in the ARP table.
Use netsh wlan show interfaces to find out the BSSID (Wi-Fi MAC) that you're connected to.

Thanks, yeah netsh wlan show interfaces works. So ARP is only a useful troubleshooting tool for ethernet connections. Interesting.

@Jibroni, Note that ARP is not really intended to be a troubleshooting tool, though in some circumstances it can be useful for that purpose.  ARPs primary purpose is to allow systems to obtain the information they need to operate layer 3 protocols like IPv4, over layer2 protocols like Ethernet.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol .

@Jibroni It's a troubleshooting tool for IP connections. WiFi emulates Ethernet and the ARP tool works the same way across both – but you have to distinguish between, let's say, the physical wireless connection (to a WiFi AP) and the data connection (to a router) that goes over the wireless connection – ARP is part of the latter and has nothing to do with the former. (Especially on larger networks where you have dozens of Wi-Fi APs giving access to the same IP router...) Even with Ethernet, the arp tool actually tells you nothing about what the cable is connected to.
